# How to make Amazon AWS API call from Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, authorization

What are my options if I want to make a call to Amazon AWS Rest API from Java.

When implementing my own request, generating the `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` Authorization header would be the hardest.

Essentially, this is the header I need to generate:

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJTOUYS27JPVRDUYQ/20200602/us-east-1/route53/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=ba85affa19fa4a8735ce952e50d41c8c93406a11d22b88cc98b109b529bcc15e
```

Comment: AWS exposes many Strongly typed Java APIs. Why are you not invoking the services using the Service clients

Comment: @smac2020 If you are talking about official [AWS SDK v1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java), or [v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2), I have tried that. They are awesome for a bit more serious tasks to perform with AWS. I wanted a solution which would involve minimum new dependencies, or ultimately no dependencies. Code like signature generation is usually quite static (does not require much of a maintenance), so copying just the source (one file) into my project seemed to be a good compromise.

Can help in other orgs with too much bureaucracy when it comes to new dependencies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not saying that this is a complete list, but I would consider using established libraries like:

- Official [AWS SDK v1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java), or [v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) - current and comprehensive but depends on [netty.io](https://netty.io) and many other jars.
- [Apache JClouds](https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/aws/) - depends on JAXB which is not longer a part of JDK but now available at maven central separately.

But sometimes, all you want is to make a simple call, and you don't want to bring many dependencies into your application. You may want to implement the rest call yourself. Generating the right AWS Authorization header is the hardest bit to implement.

Here is the code to do that in pure java OpenJDK with no external dependencies.

It implements **Amazon AWS API Signature Version 4** signing process.

AmazonRequestSignatureV4Utils.java

```java
package com.frusal.amazonsig4;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Copyright 2020 Alex Vasiliev, licensed under the Apache 2.0 license: https://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0
 */
public class AmazonRequestSignatureV4Utils {

    /**
     * Generates signing headers for HTTP request in accordance with Amazon AWS API Signature version 4 process.
     * <p>
     * Following steps outlined here: <a href="https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html">docs.aws.amazon.com</a>
     * <p>
     * Simple usage example is here: {@link AmazonRequestSignatureV4Example}
     * <p>
     * This method takes many arguments as read-only, but adds necessary headers to @{code headers} argument, which is a map.
     * The caller should make sure those parameters are copied to the actual request object.
     * <p>
     * The ISO8601 date parameter can be created by making a call to:<br>
     * - {@code java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'").format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))}<br>
     * or, if you prefer joda:<br>
     * - {@code org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis().print(DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC))}
     *
     * @param method - HTTP request method, (GET|POST|DELETE|PUT|...), e.g., {@link java.net.HttpURLConnection#getRequestMethod()}
     * @param host - URL host, e.g., {@link java.net.URL#getHost()}.
     * @param path - URL path, e.g., {@link java.net.URL#getPath()}.
     * @param query - URL query, (parameters in sorted order, see the AWS spec) e.g., {@link java.net.URL#getQuery()}.
     * @param headers - HTTP request header map. This map is going to have entries added to it by this method. Initially populated with
     *     headers to be included in the signature. Like often compulsory 'Host' header. e.g., {@link java.net.HttpURLConnection#getRequestProperties()}.
     * @param body - The binary request body, for requests like POST.
     * @param isoDateTime - The time and date of the request in ISO8601 basic format, see comment above.
     * @param awsIdentity - AWS Identity, e.g., "AKIAJTOUYS27JPVRDUYQ"
     * @param awsSecret - AWS Secret Key, e.g., "I8Q2hY819e+7KzBnkXj66n1GI9piV+0p3dHglAzQ"
     * @param awsRegion - AWS Region, e.g., "us-east-1"
     * @param awsService - AWS Service, e.g., "route53"
     */
    public static void calculateAuthorizationHeaders(
            String method, String host, String path, String query, Map<String, String> headers,
            byte[] body,
            String isoDateTime,
            String awsIdentity, String awsSecret, String awsRegion, String awsService
    ) {
        try {
            String bodySha256 = hex(sha256(body));
            String isoJustDate = isoDateTime.substring(0, 8); // Cut the date portion of a string like '20150830T123600Z';

            headers.put("Host", host);
            headers.put("X-Amz-Content-Sha256", bodySha256);
            headers.put("X-Amz-Date", isoDateTime);

            // (1) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html
            List<String> canonicalRequestLines = new ArrayList<>();
            canonicalRequestLines.add(method);
            canonicalRequestLines.add(path);
            canonicalRequestLines.add(query);
            List<String> hashedHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> headerKeysSorted = headers.keySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.toLowerCase(Locale.US))).collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (String key : headerKeysSorted) {
                hashedHeaders.add(key.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
                canonicalRequestLines.add(key.toLowerCase(Locale.US) + ":" + normalizeSpaces(headers.get(key)));
            }
            canonicalRequestLines.add(null); // new line required after headers
            String signedHeaders = hashedHeaders.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
            canonicalRequestLines.add(signedHeaders);
            canonicalRequestLines.add(bodySha256);
            String canonicalRequestBody = canonicalRequestLines.stream().map(line -> line == null ? "" : line).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            String canonicalRequestHash = hex(sha256(canonicalRequestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

            // (2) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html
            List<String> stringToSignLines = new ArrayList<>();
            stringToSignLines.add("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
            stringToSignLines.add(isoDateTime);
            String credentialScope = isoJustDate + "/" + awsRegion + "/" + awsService + "/aws4_request";
            stringToSignLines.add(credentialScope);
            stringToSignLines.add(canonicalRequestHash);
            String stringToSign = stringToSignLines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

            // (3) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html
            byte[] kDate = hmac(("AWS4" + awsSecret).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), isoJustDate);
            byte[] kRegion = hmac(kDate, awsRegion);
            byte[] kService = hmac(kRegion, awsService);
            byte[] kSigning = hmac(kService, "aws4_request");
            String signature = hex(hmac(kSigning, stringToSign));

            String authParameter = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" + awsIdentity + "/" + credentialScope + ", SignedHeaders=" + signedHeaders + ", Signature=" + signature;
            headers.put("Authorization", authParameter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) e;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String normalizeSpaces(String value) {
        return value.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
    }

    public static String hex(byte[] a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
        for(byte b: a) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
     }

    private static byte[] sha256(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(bytes);
        return digest.digest();
    }

    public static byte[] hmac(byte[] key, String msg) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256"));
        return mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

}
```

And the usage example:

AmazonRequestSignatureV4Utils.java

```java
package com.frusal.amazonsig4;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AmazonRequestSignatureV4Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String route53HostedZoneId = "Z08118721NNU878C4PBNA";
        String awsIdentity = "AKIAJTOUYS27JPVRDUYQ";
        String awsSecret = "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";
        String awsRegion = "us-east-1";
        String awsService = "route53";

        URL url = new URL("https://route53.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone/" + route53HostedZoneId + "/rrset");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        System.out.println(connection.getRequestMethod() + " " + url);

        String body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest xmlns=\"https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/\">\n" +
                "<ChangeBatch>\n" +
                // " <Comment>optional comment about the changes in this change batch request</Comment>\n" +
                "   <Changes>\n" +
                "      <Change>\n" +
                "         <Action>UPSERT</Action>\n" +
                "         <ResourceRecordSet>\n" +
                "            <Name>c001cxxx.frusal.com.</Name>\n" +
                "            <Type>A</Type>\n" +
                "            <TTL>300</TTL>\n" +
                "            <ResourceRecords>\n" +
                "               <ResourceRecord>\n" +
                "                  <Value>157.245.232.185</Value>\n" +
                "               </ResourceRecord>\n" +
                "            </ResourceRecords>\n" +
                // " <HealthCheckId>optional ID of a Route 53 health check</HealthCheckId>\n" +
                "         </ResourceRecordSet>\n" +
                "      </Change>\n" +
                "   </Changes>\n" +
                "</ChangeBatch>\n" +
                "</ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest>";
        byte[] bodyBytes = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Map<String, String> headers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String isoDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'").format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        AmazonRequestSignatureV4Utils.calculateAuthorizationHeaders(
                connection.getRequestMethod(),
                connection.getURL().getHost(),
                connection.getURL().getPath(),
                connection.getURL().getQuery(),
                headers,
                bodyBytes,
                isoDate,
                awsIdentity,
                awsSecret,
                awsRegion,
                awsService);

        // Unsigned headers
        headers.put("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); // I guess it get modified somewhere on the way... Let's just leave it out of the signature.

        // Log headers and body
        System.out.println(headers.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
        System.out.println(body);

        // Send
        headers.forEach((key, val) -> connection.setRequestProperty(key, val));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.getOutputStream().write(bodyBytes);
        connection.getOutputStream().flush();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("connection.getResponseCode()=" + responseCode);

        String responseContentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
        System.out.println("responseContentType=" + responseContentType);

        System.out.println("Response BODY:");
        if (connection.getErrorStream() != null) {
            System.out.println(new String(connection.getErrorStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } else {
            System.out.println(new String(connection.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }
}
```

And the trace it would generate:

```http
POST https://route53.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone/Z08118721NNU878C4PBNA/rrset
Host: route53.amazonaws.com
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: 46c7521da55bcf9e99fa6e12ec83997fab53128b5df0fb12018a6b76fb2bf891
X-Amz-Date: 20200602T035618Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJTOUYS27JPVRDUYQ/20200602/us-east-1/route53/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=6a59090f837cf71fa228d2650e9b82e9769e0ec13e9864e40bd2f81c682ef8cb
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/">
<ChangeBatch>
   <Changes>
      <Change>
         <Action>UPSERT</Action>
         <ResourceRecordSet>
            <Name>c001cxxx.frusal.com.</Name>
            <Type>A</Type>
            <TTL>300</TTL>
            <ResourceRecords>
               <ResourceRecord>
                  <Value>157.245.232.185</Value>
               </ResourceRecord>
            </ResourceRecords>
         </ResourceRecordSet>
      </Change>
   </Changes>
</ChangeBatch>
</ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest>
connection.getResponseCode()=200
responseContentType=text/xml
Response BODY:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><ChangeInfo><Id>/change/C011827119UYGF04GVIP6</Id><Status>PENDING</Status><SubmittedAt>2020-06-02T03:56:25.822Z</SubmittedAt></ChangeInfo></ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse>
```

Edit: Updated to sort the headers. Thanks @Gray for the find!

For the latest version of this code, please see [java-amazon-request-signature-v4](https://github.com/frusal/java-amazon-request-signature-v4) repository at GitHub.

Comment: Fixed a couple of bugs in your code with my answer @AlexV.  Thanks for the code!

Comment: Thank you @Gray, I've updated the GitHub repo with the headers sorting. As for the rest of your changes, I aimed for readability and not the performance, so perhaps I would leave it as is. But you can create a PR or branch if you wish. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make Amazon AWS API call from Java?

I took the answer from @AlexV and then fixed a couple of problems with the code.  The headers need to be sorted (case insensitively) otherwise the signature won't match.  I think I fixed a couple other issues maybe?  I also improved some of the other methods by removing unnecessary collections and optimizing the hex and trim methods.  I also changed the calculate method to return a linked hash-map of the headers so they can be put appropriately into the request.

This code matches the AWS signature documentation examples (finally) and I've successfully authenticated requests with S3.  Haven't tried other AWS services yet...

```
public class AmazonRequestSignatureV4Utils {

    /**
     * Generates signing headers for HTTP request in accordance with Amazon AWS API Signature version 4 process.
     * <p>
     * Following steps outlined here:
     * <a href="https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html">docs.aws.amazon.com</a>
     * <p>
     * The ISO8601 date parameter should look like '20150830T123600Z' and can be created by making a call to:
     * 
     * <pre>
     * java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'").format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))}
     * </pre>
     * 
     * or, if you prefer joda:
     * 
     * <pre>
     * {@code org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis().print(DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC))}
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param method
     *            HTTP request method, (GET|POST|DELETE|PUT|...), e.g.,
     *            {@link java.net.HttpURLConnection#getRequestMethod()}
     * @param host
     *            URL host, e.g., {@link java.net.URL#getHost()}.
     * @param path
     *            URL path, e.g., {@link java.net.URL#getPath()}.
     * @param query
     *            URL query, (parameters in sorted order, see the AWS spec) e.g., {@link java.net.URL#getQuery()}.
     * @param headerMap
     *            HTTP request header map. The returned map should be used in the request.
     * @param body
     *            The binary request body, for requests like POST or PUT. If null then new byte[0] will be used.
     * @param isoDateTime
     *            The time and date of the request in ISO8601 basic format like '20150830T123600Z', see comment above.
     * @param awsAccessKeyId
     *            AWS Identity, e.g., "AKIAJTOUY..."
     * @param awsSecretAccessKey
     *            AWS Secret Key, e.g., "I8Q2hY819e+7KzB..."
     * @param awsRegion
     *            AWS Region, e.g., "us-east-1"
     * @param awsService
     *            AWS Service, e.g., "route53"
     * @return Linked map of properties that should be set on the http request with no other headers.
     */
    public static Map<String, String> calculateAuthorizationHeaders(String method, String host, String path,
            String query, Map<String, String> headerMap, byte[] body, String isoDateTime, String awsAccessKeyId,
            String awsSecretAccessKey, String awsRegion, String awsService)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {

        if (body == null) {
            body = new byte[0];
        }
        String bodySha256 = hex(sha256(body));
        String isoJustDate = isoDateTime.substring(0, 8); // Cut the date portion of a string like '20150830T123600Z';

        Map<String, String> resultHeaderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // (1) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html
        StringBuilder canonicalRequestSb = new StringBuilder();
        appendOptionalString(canonicalRequestSb, method);
        appendOptionalString(canonicalRequestSb, path);
        appendOptionalString(canonicalRequestSb, query);

        final String HOST_HEADER = "Host";
        final String AMAZON_DATE_HEADER = "X-Amz-Date";
        final String AMAZON_CONTENT_HASH_HEADER = "X-Amz-Content-Sha256";

        // need to order the headers to match the AWS docs but may not be necessary for the request
        List<String> headerList = new ArrayList<>(headerMap.keySet());
        headerList.add(HOST_HEADER);
        headerList.add(AMAZON_CONTENT_HASH_HEADER);
        headerList.add(AMAZON_DATE_HEADER);
        Collections.sort(headerList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        StringBuilder hashedHeadersSb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String header : headerList) {
            String value = headerMap.get(header);
            if (header.equals(HOST_HEADER)) {
                value = host;
            } else if (header.equals(AMAZON_CONTENT_HASH_HEADER)) {
                value = bodySha256;
            } else if (header.equals(AMAZON_DATE_HEADER)) {
                value = isoDateTime;
            }
            resultHeaderMap.put(header, value);
            String headerLower = header.toLowerCase();
            if (hashedHeadersSb.length() > 0) {
                hashedHeadersSb.append(';');
            }
            hashedHeadersSb.append(headerLower);
            String cannonicalValue = headerLower + ":" + normalizeSpaces(value);
            appendOptionalString(canonicalRequestSb, cannonicalValue);
        }
        canonicalRequestSb.append('\n'); // new line required after headers

        // names of the headers, lowercase, separated by ';'
        String signedHeaders = hashedHeadersSb.toString();
        appendOptionalString(canonicalRequestSb, signedHeaders);
        appendOptionalString(canonicalRequestSb, bodySha256);
        // trim off the last newline
        canonicalRequestSb.setLength(canonicalRequestSb.length() - 1);
        String canonicalRequestBody = canonicalRequestSb.toString();
        String canonicalRequestHash = hex(sha256(canonicalRequestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

        final String AWS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";

        // (2) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html
        StringBuilder stringToSignSb = new StringBuilder();
        stringToSignSb.append(AWS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM).append('\n');
        stringToSignSb.append(isoDateTime).append('\n');
        String requestType = "aws4_request";
        String credentialScope = isoJustDate + "/" + awsRegion + "/" + awsService + "/" + requestType;
        stringToSignSb.append(credentialScope).append('\n');
        stringToSignSb.append(canonicalRequestHash);
        String stringToSign = stringToSignSb.toString();

        // (3) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html
        byte[] keySecret = ("AWS4" + awsSecretAccessKey).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] keyDate = hmac(keySecret, isoJustDate);
        byte[] keyRegion = hmac(keyDate, awsRegion);
        byte[] keyService = hmac(keyRegion, awsService);
        byte[] keySigning = hmac(keyService, requestType);
        String signature = hex(hmac(keySigning, stringToSign));

        // finally we can build our Authorization header
        String authParameter = AWS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM + " Credential=" + awsAccessKeyId + "/" + credentialScope
                + ",SignedHeaders=" + signedHeaders + ",Signature=" + signature;
        resultHeaderMap.put("Authorization", authParameter);
        return resultHeaderMap;
    }

    private static void appendOptionalString(StringBuilder sb, String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        sb.append('\n');
    }

    /** replaces multiple whitespace character blocks into a single space, removes whitespace from the front and end */
    private static String normalizeSpaces(String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.length());
        boolean prevSpace = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            char ch = value.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
                if (sb.length() == 0) {
                    // skip spaces at the start
                } else {
                    // note that we saw a space which reduces multiples and ignores spaces
                    // this filters whitespace at the end of the string because they only emitted before the next char
                    prevSpace = true;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (prevSpace) {
                // this changes all whitespace into a space
                sb.append(' ');
                prevSpace = false;
            }
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String hex(byte[] bytes) {
        final String HEX_CHARACTERS = "0123456789abcdef";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            int val = (bytes[i] & 0xFF);
            sb.append(HEX_CHARACTERS.charAt(val >>> 4));
            sb.append(HEX_CHARACTERS.charAt(val & 0x0F));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static byte[] sha256(byte[] bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(bytes);
        return digest.digest();
    }

    private static byte[] hmac(byte[] key, String input) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256"));
        return mac.doFinal(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Here's a usage example which shows the actual HTTP request being made using Apache HttpClient version 4.5.13:

```
String method = "GET";
String host = "somebucket.s3.amazonaws.com";
String path = "/somepath.txt";
String query = null;
// probably should come from a file or something if doing a PUT or POST
String body = null;
String awsIdentity = "AKIA...";
String awsSecret = "s1Zpk...";
String awsRegion = "us-west-2";
String awsService = "s3";

// optional headers
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String dateHeader = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'UTC'").format(zonedDateTime);
headers.put("Date", dateHeader);
String isoDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'").format(zonedDateTime);

// this is a linked hashmap and the headers must be in a specific order
Map<String, String> requestHeaders =
            AmazonRequestSignatureV4Utils.calculateAuthorizationHeaders(method, host, path, query, headers,
                    body.getBytes(), isoDateTime, awsIdentity, awsSecret, awsRegion, awsService);
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();) {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://" + host + path);
    List<Header> finalHeaders = new ArrayList<>(requestHeaders.size());
    // these must be in a specific order
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : requestHeaders.entrySet()) {
        finalHeaders.add(new BasicHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    // this overrides any previous headers specified
    request.setHeaders(finalHeaders.toArray(new Header[requestHeaders.size()]));
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);) {
        System.out.println("response status: " + response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("response body:");
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    }
}
```